# How to pivot rows into columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

Been looking to pivot rows (progress_check) into columns check 1, check 2 etc...
No sum or totals required, just to display the results hopefully...
Can anyone help, Thanks Ad

[image: This is the table (grades) in MYSQL]

[image: Hope to get something like this!]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way to `pivot` using standard SQL (and the part of the standard that MySQL implements). That means it not only works in MySQL, but also in most SQL databases:

```
SELECT
    r0.sims_id, 
    r0.subject, 
    r1.result AS "C1",
    r2.result AS "C2",
    r3.result AS "C3"
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        sims_id, subject
     FROM 
         results
     ) r0
    LEFT JOIN results r1 
        ON r1.sims_id = r0.sims_id AND r1.subject = r0.subject AND r1.progress_check = 'C1'
    LEFT JOIN results r2 
        ON r2.sims_id = r0.sims_id AND r2.subject = r0.subject AND r2.progress_check = 'C2'
    LEFT JOIN results r3 
        ON r3.sims_id = r0.sims_id AND r3.subject = r0.subject AND r3.progress_check = 'C3'
ORDER BY
    r0.sims_id, r0.subject ;
```

Check it at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ef46c/2/0)

Although for this kind of problems `(sims_id, subject-id, progress_check)` should be a `PRIMARY KEY` (or, at least, `UNIQUE`), using this method, it there are *repeated* values for "C1", "C2" or "C3" for one single sims_id, subject... the *cartesian product* of all available information appears in the result. No information is lost, but it is not summarised either. Whether this behaviour is desirable or not depends on the use-case.

Answer (score 12):

GROUP BY and using MAX or SUM is the most used standard pivot way.

```
SELECT 
   results.sims_id
 , results.subject 
 , MAX(CASE WHEN results.progress_check = "C1" THEN results.result END) "C1"
 , MAX(CASE WHEN results.progress_check = "C2" THEN results.result END) "C2"
 , MAX(CASE WHEN results.progress_check = "C3" THEN results.result END) "C3"
FROM 
 results
GROUP BY
   results.sims_id
 , results.subject 
ORDER BY
    results.sims_id ASC
  , results.subject ASC
```

**Result**

```
sims_id  subject  C1      C2      C3      
-------  -------  ------  ------  --------
   1111  Art      C       B       (NULL)  
   1111  English  6       5       (NULL)  
   1111  History  B       C       (NULL)  
   1111  maths    8       8       (NULL)  
   1111  science  A       B       (NULL)  
   2222  Art      (NULL)  A       (NULL)  
   2222  English  6               (NULL)  
   2222  ICT      A       B       (NULL)  
   2222  maths    7       6       (NULL)  
   2222  science  A       A*      (NULL)
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0be1f2/1